# Como sumar elementos de un indexOf

Tags: javascript, array, bucle-for, bucles

Tengo que hacer un ejercicio que consiste en recorrer el siguiente array:

```
let original = [true,false,false,true,false,true,true,false];
```

si el valor es **true**, hay que sumarle dos posiciones, coger dicho elemento y colocarlo en un array vacío.

Por lo tanto, el nuevo array tendría que quedar:

```
let nuevo = [false,true,false]
```

Alguien sabe como se podría conseguir? se puede utilizar cualquier bucle, no tiene porque ser con for.

A ver es una tarea que no se ni como empezar y necesito ayuda, por eso he preguntado por aquí (en respuesta a uno de los comentarios)

En primer lugar no se como operar con elementos del índice (de ahí mi pregunta)

Lo que tengo hecho es el principio de la función pero (evidentemente) no funciona.

```
let original = [true,false,false,true,false,true,true,false]

function bucle (t){ 
  let nueva = []

  for(let i of t ) {
    if (i == true){

    // no se q poner en la condición

    }
  }

  return nueva;
} document.getElementById("caja1").innerHTML=La cadena original es: ${original} <br> La nueva cadena es ${bucle(original)};
```

No he encontrado nada que me haya podido servir.

Comment: 2 cosas, la primera que haz intentado? cuales son tus avances? y segundo, la parte de *si el valor es true, hay que sumarle dos, coger dicho elemento y colocarlo en otro array vacío* no se entiende muy bien puedes explicar mejor esa parte.

Comment: Bienvenido a SO en español!  Léete [ask] y realiza el [tour] para aprender el funcionamiento del sitio y el tipo de preguntas aceptadas. En este caso esta pregunta no cumple con los requisitos de un [example], ni muestra ningún código ni tampoco ningún error que hayas tenido, es simplemente una tarea que quieres que hagan por ti, y aqui **no hacemos tareas ni código a medida**, ayudamos con problemas de código que nos debeis mostrar. Puedes [edit] tu pregunta agregando lo que has hecho para que podamos ayudarte, en caso contrario será cerrada.

Comment: Bueno, gracias, eso ya es otra cosa, no es perfecta pero mejor que antes. A ver, yo de ti haria un `for` tipico con numeros de indice, como el que ves en su [documentación](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for), y en lugar del 9 que ves alli le pones `original.length` que representa el numero total de elementos que tiene ese array

Comment: El condicional, visto eso, y aprovechandonos de la `i` seria algo asi como `if (original[i] == true){` ... y ya casi lo tienes... es decir, si sabes acceder a un valor del original mediante la i, que representa el número de indice del array en cada ciclo... ¿que debes hacer para que si la condición se cumple localizar el que esta 2 posiciones más adelante?  ¿como lo identificas?  Si contestas eso te sigo ayudando :-)

Answer (score 1):

Analiza el problema y piénsalo sin código:

- Debes recorrer cada elemento del arreglo hasta la **antepenúltima** posición. Solo hasta la **antepenúltima** porque si encuentras algún `true` en la penúltima o última posición no podrás moverte dos pasos hacia la derecha, ¡porque en el arreglo no hay más nada dos pasos a la derecha!.
- Para cada elemento que recorras debes preguntar si es es `true`, si es `true`, entonces te mueves dos posiciones a la derecha y guardas ese elemento.

Los arreglos en `javascript` se indexan desde 0, y se accede a su valor iésimo por la notación `arreglo[i]`. El tamaño de un arreglo está dado por `arreglo.length`, por tanto, el penúltimo elemento es `arreglo.length - 3`.

Para resolver tu problema, simplemente combina un ciclo `for` donde recorras el arreglo hasta el penúltimo elemento, y por cada uno preguntes si es `true`. Si lo es, muévete a la izquierda y agrega ese elemento al arreglo de salida.

```js
let original = [true, false, false, true, false, true, true, false];

let nuevo = [];  // Nuevo arreglo para guardar la salida

// Para cada elemento del arreglo (solo llegando hasta el antepenúltimo)
for (let i = 0; i <= original.length - 3; i++) {
    if (original[i]) {   // Si es true
        nuevo.push(original[i + 2]); // Guarda en nuevo el elemento que está
                                     //  dos posiciones a su derecha
    }
}

console.log(nuevo);  // Imprime el arreglo nuevo
```